# What is wrong with this Azure function code?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Just doing a simple test of Azure Functions.

Below is the DEFAULT code created when I add a function. In the code, you will see the original, commented out code which works just fine. Above that you will see the modified code that causes a 500 Internal Server Error. Now, at risk of looking like a complete idiot, I'm posting here, but super frustrated I'm wasting more than 5 seconds on this.

```html
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

//  This code doesn't work (500 Internal Server Error)
    string responseMessage = "Hi!"
    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);

//  This default code does work
//    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
//        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
//                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";
//
//            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to find in the telemetry where the compilation errors are.  It's not super-obvious in the edit-on-the-web experience.  It's much easier when  you develop and test in VS Code or Visual Studio.

This

```
    string responseMessage = "Hi!"
    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
```

is missing a `;` on the first line.

Comment: Oh my goodness. I'm really getting ahead of myself here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When I return from a function, I do this:

```
var response = request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
// add some headers to the response, like:
response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

// and then something like:
await response.WriteStringAsync(stuffToReturn); //(or could be WriteBytesAsync)

// and
return response;
```